# How to mask the "&" character in a URL

Tags: url, masking

I have got a URL where  the character `&` should not stand for a paramter. How can I mask it that it is interpreted like a normal letter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Input `%26` in place of the `&`

The important term in this situation is: **url encoding**